# How to change the UILabel text by clicking the UIButton every time with a new word in iPhone app development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a UILabel I can change it to another string by clicking the button but how to display the number for every time of clicking the button on UILabel.

Comment: create a variable to use as index and increment this variable every time the user taps the button and update your UILabel text propriety with the respective index.

Comment: Hint: event handling

Comment: Instance variable and properties. iOS 101. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare NSInteger clickNumber; globally
In viewDidload, 
clickNumber=0;
in buttonaction method
clickNumber=clickNumber+1;
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", clickNumber];
label.text = numberString;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

view controller.h..

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
 int click;
}
- (IBAction)btnclick:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *click_lbl;

@end
```

view controller.m....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
  click=0;
}
- (IBAction)btnclick:(id)sender 
{

 click++;

self.click_lbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",click];
}
```